# java text dialog, which button was clicked?

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I followed official guide for java dialogs so I have this code:

```
String s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this, "Text\n\nEnter your name", "Heading", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
```

How can I check if an user clicked OK or cancel button?

Comment: The string returned by showInputDialog will be null. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInputDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20javax.swing.Icon,%20java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object%29

Comment: nope, it will contain user input

Comment: Sorry, but not only does the API states this to be the case (to quote: 'returns...user's input, or null meaning the user canceled the input'), but it performs as expected when I run this on my system. If you find something incorrect, I recommend editing your question so the appropriate context is available to answer you question correctly.

Comment: yes, it's my bad I haven't noticed that. Quoted text is exactly answer to my question. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this, "Text\n\nEnter your name", "Heading", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
if (input!=null) { ....}
```

Note that when the user clicks on "cancel", `input` will be **null**.

So you can try like this if you want to check if the user clicks Cancel or OK button

```
String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this, "Text\n\nEnter your name", "Heading", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
if (input != null) { 
 // functionality for the OK button click
} else {
 // functionality for the Cancel button click
}
```

Comment: I need input box in that dialog, edit: updated code is not solving which button has user clicked

Answer (score 2):

[showInputDialog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInputDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20javax.swing.Icon,%20java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object%29):

> Returns:
>  user's input, or null meaning the user canceled the input

If method call returns `null`, then the user pressed *cancel*. Otherwise, if he pressed *ok*, it will contain the user input.